# If the running time is short ( 2 ms), would it be worth to use multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I wrote a Java program. For a small input, after warm-up (the first 50 runs), its running time turns to be around 2 milliseconds.

In this case, could we get any benefit if I use multiple threads version? If not, what are the overhead hidden the benefits of parallel execution?

Comment: The phrase "it depends" sure applies here. Is 2 ms not acceptable to your application? Is tradeoff between a possible performance improvement of multithreading worth the extra complexity introduced? Multithreading is not a guaranteed way of improving performance.

Comment: You seriously want to split a 2ms calculation into multiple threads? The overhead will be humongous.

Comment: 'If I use multiple thread' for *what?* What's the nature of the program?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the overhead of starting the threads would far outweigh any speedup. On windows you'll even have trouble measuring the execution time reliably for such fast programs.

But of course, you must ask yourself if you truly need any speedup for a program that runs in 2 ms.

Comment: 'Most likely the overhead of starting the threads would far outweigh any speedup'..unless the threads already exist, ie. pooled or dedicated 'app-lifetime' threads.

Comment: @Martin James: True. I was assuming his entire app runs in 2ms.

Answer (score 0):

Id depends on if 2ms is too slow. It also depends if you want to run the tasks concurrently.
Why not use an Executor to run your tasks then you can add threads as you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 2ms is at least a candidate for splitting up over multiple threads.  Continually creating/running/terminating/joining threads is a non-starter - hopeless design.  If signaling work to a set of dedicated threads or issuing work to a pool, it all depends on the work done and the data organization.

If there is any blocking, or CPU-intensive, work that an be effectively performed in parallel in those 2ms, then you could give it a go.  The key issue with CPU-intensive work is how much data and how it is organized.  If the data to be worked on can easily be chopped up into nice, [L1-cache-size or smaller] chunks, you're onto a winner.  If not, be prepared for a dissapointment.

You could, of course, try it and see..